# How can i see MACD signal by using stockstats?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, stockstats

I'm trying to draw a Macd indicator. I am using stockstats to draw it. But I can only see the Macd value.(and can not add it to csv file if you help me to add it too I'll be glad) how can i see MACD_EMA_SHORT,MACD_EMA_LONG,MACD_EMA_SIGNAL with stockstats?
and trying to draw it like the picture.

[image]

Following is my attempt:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import requests
from stockstats import StockDataFrame as sdf

periods = '3600'
resp = requests.get('https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/poloniex/ethusdt/ohlc', params={'periods': periods})
data=resp.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['result'][periods], columns=[
    'CloseTime', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume','Adj Volume'])
df.to_csv('eth.csv')
df=pd.read_csv('eth.csv', parse_dates=True,index_col=0)
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df['CloseTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CloseTime'], unit='s')
df = df.set_index('CloseTime')
#print(df.tail(6))


data=pd.read_csv('eth.csv')

stock=sdf.retype(data)
signal=stock['macd_ema_short']

df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(signal)
```

Error:

> KeyError: 'macd_ema_short'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### MACD_EMA_SHORT is only a class method

- you can't get it, unless you update the `class`

  - you need to return `fast = df[ema_short]`
- MACD_EMA_SHORT is a parameter used for a calculation in `_get_macd`

  - `MACD_EMA_SHORT = 12`
  - `ema_short = 'close_{}_ema'.format(cls.MACD_EMA_SHORT)`
  - `ema_short = 'close_12_ema'`

```py
class StockDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    OPERATORS = ['le', 'ge', 'lt', 'gt', 'eq', 'ne']

    # Start of options.
    KDJ_PARAM = (2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0)
    KDJ_WINDOW = 9

    BOLL_PERIOD = 20
    BOLL_STD_TIMES = 2

    MACD_EMA_SHORT = 12
    MACD_EMA_LONG = 26
    MACD_EMA_SIGNAL = 9
```

```py
    @classmethod
    def _get_macd(cls, df):
        """ Moving Average Convergence Divergence
        This function will initialize all following columns.
        MACD Line (macd): (12-day EMA - 26-day EMA)
        Signal Line (macds): 9-day EMA of MACD Line
        MACD Histogram (macdh): MACD Line - Signal Line
        :param df: data
        :return: None
        """
        ema_short = 'close_{}_ema'.format(cls.MACD_EMA_SHORT)
        ema_long = 'close_{}_ema'.format(cls.MACD_EMA_LONG)
        ema_signal = 'macd_{}_ema'.format(cls.MACD_EMA_SIGNAL)
        fast = df[ema_short]
        slow = df[ema_long]
        df['macd'] = fast - slow
        df['macds'] = df[ema_signal]
        df['macdh'] = (df['macd'] - df['macds'])
        log.critical("NOTE: Behavior of MACDH calculation has changed as of "
                     "July 2017 - it is now 1/2 of previous calculated values")
        cls._drop_columns(df, [ema_short, ema_long, ema_signal])
```

### Update:

- find `stockstats.py`, then in `def _get_macd(cls, df)`, comment out `cls._drop_columns(df, [ema_short, ema_long, ema_signal])` (e.g. put `#` in front of it)
- Then you can do `stock['close_12_ema']`

#### Code to get the table:

```py
periods = '3600'
resp = requests.get('https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/poloniex/ethusdt/ohlc', params={'periods': periods})
data = resp.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['result'][periods], columns=['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'amount'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s')

stock = sdf.retype(df)
print(stock['macds'])

print(stock)
```

- The extra columns don't get added until you do `stock['macds']`.

#### OUtput:

```py
                           open        high         low       close      volume        amount  close_12_ema  close_26_ema      macd  macd_9_ema     macds     macdh
date                                                                                                                                                               
2019-08-20 00:00:00  201.000000  203.379326  201.000000  202.138224  349.209128  70720.937575    202.138224    202.138224  0.000000    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2019-08-20 01:00:00  202.187160  202.650000  200.701061  200.778709  329.485014  66411.899720    201.401820    201.432322 -0.030502   -0.016946 -0.016946 -0.013556
2019-08-20 02:00:00  201.200000  201.558777  200.133667  200.338312   12.812929   2572.209909    200.986733    201.039255 -0.052522   -0.031526 -0.031526 -0.020996
2019-08-20 03:00:00  200.915590  201.177018  200.396571  200.440000   21.910910   4395.692727    200.814151    200.871730 -0.057579   -0.040352 -0.040352 -0.017227
2019-08-20 04:00:00  200.979999  200.979999  198.282603  198.644618  360.432424  71712.376256    200.224696    200.355253 -0.130557   -0.067186 -0.067186 -0.063371
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help 
maybe trying to calculate by help of _EMA12,26,9_ can be a easy way do to .

Comment: It seems weird that the package author would choose to drop those columns from the DataFrame.

Comment: lol. but in my opinion **macd ema short** is the most valueable indicator for buying and selling.

Comment: now time for mathplotlib ... i m really thankful for your help... and i can not vote because of reputation when i get 15 i wil do it too

Comment: I am really sorry but may i ask you that with which code did you get last table? I can get datas of  close_26_ema  and other datas but can not get a table like yours.

Comment: sorry i need to ask one more question.
this is my output of macds.
2019-09-11 09:00:00   -0.388789
2019-09-11 10:00:00   -0.424185
2019-09-11 11:00:00   -0.438202
2019-09-11 12:00:00   -0.444985
2019-09-11 13:00:00   -0.456696
if i need to use **-0.438202** only this value with which code i can use it as integer?(sorry for misspelling i have tried  to edit but i can not do it)

Comment: @AlperAşan for this example, you could use `stock['macds'].loc['2019-09-11 11:00:00']` or `stock['macds'].iloc[2]`.  [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: If we come from the bottom count how we need to do because i have copied 5 but i ve got nearly 400 (i dont know real number) in a row. and if i need bottom second one what should i have to use?

Comment: Count backwards `stock['macds'].iloc[-2]`.  You either have to use the exact index name for `.loc` or the exact index number for `.iloc`.

Comment: i have just typing [-2]. thanks alot @Trenton_M when i finish my code my i send it to you for cheking?

Comment: You can, but I'm not an expert at stock analysis or using this particular package.  I'd say, if you get the results you're expecting, then the code is good.  In fact, I've never used this package before installing it to answer your question.  I've got to head out, so I'm not going to be back on SO until later.

Comment: i m good at stock analysis but not good at python. :) my main problem is this. have a nice day. see you soon